# textbox return each result

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a simple function:

```
void licz()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        wynik = +i;
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;               
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Wynik: " + result);
}
```

And I want, the textBox1 showing everyone result (step by step). Now is showing just finish result, the same as MessageBox (Wynik: 19).

Comment: Have you tried running it on a veeeeery slooooooow machine? I think it might help

Comment: Also you doesn't seem to change your `result` variable so it is not clear why anything should be different between different `MessageBox` calls

Comment: indeed I'm not sure that code is complete.

Comment: Come on, post real code. `result` is not changing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should change to this?

```
textBox1.Text += result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the current string to the result from the previous iteration:

```
textBox1.Text += result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

or

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

...which is basically the same thing. However this will only print twenty zeros.

Answer (score 2):

You override the text in evry loop. Try

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

or better:

```
textBox1.Text += result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

textbox has one line ,
if you need more than one line you have to use RichTextBox

Comment: TextBox has a Multiline property.

Answer (score 1):

I made several changes so the code makes more sense and maybe it fixes your problem

```
void licz()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        result += i;
        textBox1.Text += result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;               
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Wynik: " + result);
}
```

Comment: Short version `void licz(){for(int i=0;i<20;i++)textBox1Text+=i+"\n";}`